# Xunit new in memory database DBContext Class has live data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, blazor, in-memory-database

I am trying to unit test with the EF Core in-memory database like so:

```
namespace ContosoTests
{
    public class TrendServiceTests
    {
       private static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<TestContext> options = new 
       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestContext>()
                       .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                       .Options;

       private static TestContext _context = new TestContext(options);

       private readonly TrendService trendService = new TrendService(_context);

        private void SeedInMemoryDb()
        {
            if (!_context.TrendHistories.Any())
            {
                _context.TrendHistories.Add(new TrendHistory { IsActive = true, Quarter = E_Quarter.Q1, 
                TrendYear = 2020 });
            }

            if (!_context.Controls.Any())
            {
                _context.Controls.Add(new Control { IsActive = true});
                _context.Controls.Add(new Control { IsActive = true});
                _context.Controls.Add(new Control { IsActive = false});
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

My TestContext inherits from my live context class to avoid the error:
*Services for database providers 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory', 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' have been registered in the service provider. Only a single database provider can be registered in a service provider*

So my TestContext just looks like:

```
public class TestContext : ContosoContext
    {
        public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options)
        {
            
        }

        public TestContext()
        {

        }
    }
```

When I use the new instance of TestContext (_context) in my test class, all the live data for ContosoContext is there.
I was expecting it to be a new instance of the context class with no data so that I could test my DAL code with controlled data. But this is not the case.

I am fairly new to unit testing so any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:**
Here are the relevant parts of my contoso context class

```
    public class ContosoContext: IdentityDbContext<ContosoApplicationUser>
    {
        public ContosoContext(DbContextOptions<ContosoContext> options) : base 
        (options)
        {

        }

        public ContosoContext()
        {

        }

        //all my DBSets here

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder 
        optionsBuilder)
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");

        }
    }
```

So the issue is that my onconfiguring method handles the connection string directly??

Comment: It seems that your `ContosoContext` does something weird with the `ServiceProvider`. The `ContosoContext` should solely rely on the injected `DbContextOptions` for configuring the connection. So, without explicitly injecting a configuration containing the 'live' connection string, it shouldn't be able to connect to that database. Probably it would be helpful if you copied the content (or at least the relevant parts) of `ContosoContext` into the question. :)

Comment: Also, generally speaking you don't need that `TestContext`. If I understand correctly that the system under test is the `ContosoContext`, you should use that directly to make the test representative of your live system (with respect to the given component). Plus that constructor in `TestContext` is currently not doing anything with the db config to begin with. But it probably all will be clear if we see your `ContosoContext`. (And that will be most likely enough to post a helpful answer.)

Comment: Oh I see now that `TrendService` is the SUT. I'm blind, apparently. But then to unit test it you'd want to isolate it from other components, meaning that you'd mock the `ContosoContext`. Testing multiple components is more like integration testing (which is fine too, and actually gives you a higher level of confidence). Anyhow, show your `ContosoContext`, and we can continue from there. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the error you need to remove `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");` in `OnConfiguring` method to avoid registering multiple database providers, change it to this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");
}
```

Comment: You were right, this solved my issue and now I can do away with the TestContext class I was using

Comment: Yes you don't need extra `TestContext`